# XML validation gone bad

Tags: xml, validation

So I have this xml file and it won't validate because each time it gives me :

[XML verification error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpuEY.jpg)

**This is the code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MaintenanceDeliveryConfirmationResponse
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OwnerId>31</OwnerId>
<ConfirmationDate>2022-06-20</ConfirmationDate>
<Code></Code>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ds saml2 saml2p xenc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<DigestValue></DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</MaintenanceDeliveryConfirmationResponse>
```

Comment: The "XML document" seems to be missing the line ` xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">` - are you sure that you're sending the data you think you're sending? Since the verification is done against a document missing that line, the first element tag never has a `>`, which seems to be the error message as well.

Comment: Please post everything needed to answer the question on this site, rather than linking to external sites which may well be transient.

Comment: Sorry about that jpg , so how properly should this code look to be validated ?